# How is "Suzanne" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, names

I want to know how to pronounce the name, Suzanne. I check dictionary but I don't find anything please help me right now

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about people's names, not the English language

Comment: In the US, the female name spelt variously as _Susanne, Suzanne,_ or _Suzann_ is normally pronounced /su'zæn/ (to rhyme with _Who's Anne?_). [Phonemic symbols here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf).

Comment: I am very very very sad

Comment: What's there to be sad about? You have a perfectly respectable answer, including an audio file. That person did something for you, something which you could have found out yourself with a little bit of effort.

Comment: I am sad because somebody on hold my question (not this question) If I have enough information about my question I didn't ask anymore I'm only 20 years old and they gave negative mark and vote for me

Comment: Think about how you can improve your question and make it more interesting for people to answer. Being 20 years old is not an excuse for being lazy, and why haven't you upvoted Pat J's answer?

Comment: No I'm not lazy. Actually I don't have enough information about this site. Can you help me for how can I vote?

Comment: A person's name is pronounced however which way that person wants it to be pronounced. Proper nouns are not constrained by the conventions of common nouns.

Comment: Mr Pat J told me about answer my question was correctly. Why are you say this things? Are you OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Around here it's pronounced `sue-ZAN`, pretty much the way the French pronounce it.

#### References

(found by Googling `suzanne pronunciation`)

- http://inogolo.com/pronunciation/Suzanne
- http://www.pronouncenames.com/pronounce/suzanne (this one has a [YouTube clip of the French pronunciation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zixFeVPNyU))

Comment: PS: by "around here" I mean the Canadian province of Manitoba.